# FreezingException with Koin in Korlin/Native

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, koin

im trying to run an app in Kotlin/Native targeted to macOs. And met an exception i can not fix:

> Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.concurrent.FreezingException:
> freezing of
> savrov.sdk.store.client.feature.product.di.ProductModule@d0414e08 has
> failed, first blocker is org.koin.core.scope.ScopeDefinition@cea8c1fa

this is my main.kt class where exception above appears:

```
// run console app
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    startKoin {
        modules(ProductModule.di())
    }
    // run some command in console 
    MainNavigationCommand().main(args)
}
```

Can someone pls navigate me how to solve it? Thank you

update:
my full stacktrace:

```
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.concurrent.FreezingException: freezing of savrov.sdk.store.client.feature.product.di.ProductModule@7e70d048 has failed, first blocker is org.koin.core.scope.ScopeDefinition@cea8c1fa
    at 0   sample.kexe                         0x0000000105a794df ThrowFreezingException + 511
    at 1   sample.kexe                         0x0000000105b69865 FreezeSubgraph + 6597
    at 2   sample.kexe                         0x0000000105b67e0a InitSharedInstanceStrict + 1050
    at 3   sample.kexe                         0x0000000105b430f5 kfun:savrov.sdk.store.client.sample.$main$lambda-0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$13.invoke#internal + 149
    at 4   sample.kexe                         0x0000000105b42c73 kfun:savrov.sdk.store.client.sample#main(kotlin.Array<kotlin.String>){} + 3379
    at 5   sample.kexe                         0x0000000105b5d8b1 Init_and_run_start + 353
    at 6   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20395621 start + 1
    at 7   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

Comment: Are you using the v3 alpha version of koin that supports Kotlin Multiplatform?

Comment: A little more info here fwiw https://johnoreilly.dev/posts/kotlinmultiplatform-koin/ (though it's moved up to `3.0.0-alpha-4` since then)...I believe hope is to integrate this in to "main" release in near future.

Comment: You'll have to give more info on the stack. The MP version of koin won't allow you to freeze Koin itself, which means you can only access it from the main thread.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly, yes, I'm using a `org.koin:koin-core:3.0.0-alpha-4` version. I have read your blog post before (:

Comment: What version of kotlinx coroutines are you using?

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly, 1.4.1. Gonna try 1.4.2

Comment: Also, I believe you might also need to use `native-mt` version

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly, I do believe I do some basics totally wrong. nm, gonna google some more info/tutorials

Comment: Might also be useful to check/compare dependencies in https://github.com/joreilly/PeopleInSpace ....that has a macOS target as well